# using countries json with selectize plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, selectize.js

I'm sorry for the question it maybe easy but I tried many and many with no result, I can't understand the concept of using json with plugin [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) .. 
I'm trying to load json file contains countries, to display it in select field in my form.
I found countries json file on [github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Keeguon/2310008/raw/865a58f59b9db2157413e7d3d949914dbf5a237d/countries.json).
this is my js code

```
$('select#country').selectize({
        valueField: 'item',
        labelField: 'item',
        options: 'countries.json'
    });
```

I read plugin usage documentation but i had confused. I need help example of using json or parsing json to object to use it with selectize plugin !

Comment: no answer ! i need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
$('select#country').selectize({
        valueField: 'id',
        labelField: 'country_name',
        options: 'countries.json'
    });
```

Then you can pass JSON values :

```
[{"id":"1","country_name":"Australia"},{"id":"2","country_name":"Belgium"} ]
```